# installing gtk and glib

Tags: linux, gtk, glib

hi every one kindly tell me how to install glib and gtk i am using ubuntu 10.04. i did;nt find any commands kindly tell me the procedure to install it

Answer (score 16):

Simply type:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

`glib` is a dependency so it will be installed too. Also you might be interested in installing `glade` as i remember it installs a `gtk` reference too:

```
sudo apt-get install glade
```

Comment: thank u osman sir. i have types the command but its saying 7 hr remaining .is it fine i mean such large time thanks

Comment: That's a very long time. If you have a slow internet connection then this might be the problem. If you have a fast connection you might try downloading the packages and their dependencies from http://packages.ubuntu.com/ and install them manually.

Answer (score 7):

And once you install them with apt-get, you can easily look up how are they called in your library list using the following command:

`pkg-config --list-all | grep query`

You replace "query" with "glib" for example, in the result you can find:

`glib-2.0                         GLib - C Utility Library`

So when you compile your code and you want to link your library with pkg-config, you can use this command:

`` gcc -o example example.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags glib-2.0` ``